# Read 2 lines of a file into a dataframe with two columns using pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, file-io, pandas

I have data files that look like this:

```
2.83  
25.56  
3.01  
33.21  
3.33  
41.41
```

Can I read them into a pandas dataframe with 2 columns in a one-line-solution with pandas read_csv()?

Comment: That looks like one column only. How do you want them in two columns?

Comment: Sorry omitted my intent: it is a time series with 2 lines for each period e.g. I want the first row of two columns to be 2.83   25.56  and the next to be 3.01  33.21 ...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None).values.reshape(-1,2)
array([[  2.83,  25.56],
       [  3.01,  33.21],
       [  3.33,  41.41]])
```

You can convert it into a DataFrame if desired:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None).values.reshape(-1,2))
      0      1
0  2.83  25.56
1  3.01  33.21
2  3.33  41.41
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, squeeze=True).reshape(-1,2))
```

Comment: Thanks the .values.reshape method works for getting my data into 2 columns `df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(symbol_lookup,header=None,skiprows=4).values.reshape(-1,2))`  but I was unsuccessful on all three methods to include a names=['earnings','price'] parameter.

Comment: The correct parameter for the DataFrame constructor is `columns`, not `names`